# Python command execution output

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running shell command from python and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

I want to capture the output of a command into a variable, so later that variable can be used again. I need to change this script so it does that:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
command = raw_input("Enter command: ")
os.system(command)
```

If I enter "ls" when I run this script, I get this output:

```
Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Videos
```

I want to capture that string (the output of the ls command) into a variable so I can use it again later. How do I do this?

Answer (score 9):

```
import subprocess
command = raw_input("Enter command: ")
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, error = p.communicate()
```

Answer (score 2):

The output of the command can be captured with the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, specifically, the [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) function..

```
output = subprocess.check_output("ls")
```

See also the documentation for [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) for the argument list that [`check_output`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) takes.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I've done it in the past.

```
>>> import popen2
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: The popen2 module is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.
>>> exec_cmd = popen2.popen4("echo shell test")
>>> output = exec_cmd[0].read()
>>> output
'shell test\n'
```

Comment: All of the old popen interfaces are deprecated in favor of subprocess.

Comment: @Chris I was wondering what "DeprecationWarning: The popen2 module is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module." meant...

Comment: Sarcasm. Yes I've heard tell of such things.

Comment: On a serious note, his sha-bang is `#!/usr/bin/python`, which means he's using a 2.x rather than a 3.x, and `subprocess.check_output` didn't come along until 2.7, so I figured giving him the old way of doing it had the most likely chance of success.  I left the deprecation warning in the console output so it would be clear there's a newer way to do it, if he has the latest version of Python.

Comment: A shebang of `/usr/bin/python` means whatever it means. I run arch linux and `/usr/bin/python` is version 3. Version 2 is located at `/usr/bin/python2`.

Comment: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2008-March/012421.html for reference.  That doesn't mean that individual distros aren't free to do the wrong thing.  IIRC Gentoo is also looking to make the 2 -> 3 symlink switch.  But... if you've successfully built and administered your own arch or gentoo box, you're probably not using stackoverflow as a google proxy.

Comment: @Chris let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1596/discussion-between-ironchefpython-and-chris)