# Shell script in python with variables

Tags: python, shell

Im still new to python.
I have a text file with a list of numbers, and each number has two 'attributes' along with it:

```
250 121 6000.654
251 8472 650.15614
252 581  84.2
```

i want to search for the 1st column and return the 2nd and 3rd columns as separate variables so i can use them later.

```
cmd = """ cat new.txt | nawk '/'251'/{print $2}' """
os.system(cmd)
```

This works in that it prints the $2 column, but i want to assign this output to a variable, something like this (however this returns the number of errors AFAIK):

```
cmdOutput =  os.system(cmd)
```

also i would like to change the nawk'd value based on a variable, something like this:

```
cmd = """ cat new.txt | nawk '/'$input'/{print $2}' """
```

If anyone can help, thanks.

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736627/python-command-execution-output/6736689#6736689

Comment: can you give us the output, like what it is printing?

Comment: Why you're trying to use awk for that, when you can use pure Python easily?

Comment: taking a look at that link now thanks
this:
'/'251'/{print $2}'
will print:
8472

im not sure how to do this in python alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `cat` and `nawk`.  Please.

Just use Python

```
import sys
target= raw_input( 'target: ' ) # or target= sys.argv[1]
with open('new.txt','r') as source:
    for columns in ( raw.strip().split() for raw in source ):
        if column[0] == target: print column[1]
```

No `cat`.  No `nawk`.

Comment: Thanks you've set me on the right path for sure. Sorry about using awk, rookie mistake!

Comment: @Kilizo: You have Python.  You don't need much more.  You barely need the shell.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to format the cmd string, use

```
input = '251'
cmd = """ cat new.txt | nawk '/'{input}'/{{print $2}}' """.format(input=input)
```

But really, you don't need an external command at all.

```
input = '251'
with open('new.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in file:
        lst = line.split()
        if lst[0] == input:
            column2, column3 = int(lst[1]), float(lst[2])
            break
    else: # the input wasn't found
        column2, column3 = None, None
print(column2, column3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
subprocess.Popen(["cat", "new.txt","|","nawk","'/'$input/{print $2}'"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
```